# Pass in options hash via ArraySerializer new syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, active-model-serializers

Is it possible to call the ArraySerializer constructor like this:

```
  mi_tmp[:notes]=ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(mi.notes, each_serializer: NotesSerializer, show_extra:false)
```

And then in the serializer:

```
  .....
  if @options[show_extra]
    attributes :user_id
  end
```

I get the error:

> Error: undefined local variable or method `show_extra' for
> NotesSerializer:Class

but can't find an example using this type of syntax.

### Edit 1

First thing I tried but no luck:

```
  mi_tmp[:notes]=ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(mi.notes, each_serializer: NotesSerializer, @options{ show_extra: false } )
```

Comment: what about `@options[:show_extra]`? (Using a symbol as key for the hash and not the variable `show_extra`)

Comment: thx - I updated with the syntax I tried first but that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpfull for you and its work fine for me

1.In books controller

```
# books contain a collection of books

books = serialize books, BookSerializer, {root: false, user_book_details: user_book_details}

# custom method

def serialize data, serializer, options = {}
    data.map do |d|
      serializer.new(d, options)
    end    
end
```

2.In book serializer

```
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  def initialize object, options = {}
    @user_book_details = options[:user_book_details]
    super object, options
  end

  attributes :id, :title, :short_description, :author_name, :image, :time_ago, :has_audio, :book_state

  # You can access @user_book_details anywhere inside the serializer

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically have attributes serialized, you need to use the magic include_xxx? methods:

```
class NotesSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :user_id

  def include_user_id?
    @options[:show_extra]
  end
end
```